# Vue: is it possible to manipulate data passed through a slot

Tags: vue.js, slot

Is it possible to modify HTML code passed through a slot?

Here is an example to clarify my question. I have two components `dropdown` and `dropdownItem`. I'm passing `dropdownItem`s to `dropdown` through the default slot.

```html
<dropdown> 
 <dropdownItem> Option 1</dropdownItem>
 <dropdownItem> Option 2</dropdownItem>
</dropdown>
```

Is it possible, inside the `dropdown` component, to manipulate the `dropdownItem`s I get through the slot? E.g., if I want to retrieve some attribute for each `dropdownItem`.

Comment: Manipulating indicates that you want to mutate the DOM in the slot, but it seems like you simply want to read out some attributes instead. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to read the data of some items and filter them.

Comment: You have to manage the list of items passed into the slot in the parent component (where you wrote this code). If you then have something within `dropdown` that you want to use to filter your items, you can use props/events to send it to this parent component, which it can then use to calculate a new list of items.